# import and read all files from a folder Python

Tags: python, import, blender

Hi everyone i am beginner with python and i have a problem with my code i would like to import and read all the .BVH file from a specific folder but the program takes only the first one from the folder.Here is my code.I use blender for visualization.

```
import bpy # This module gives access to blender data, classes, and functions
import os # This module provides a unified interface to a number of operating system functions.
import sys # This module provides a number of functions and variables that can be used to manipulate different parts of the Python runtime environment.

path = "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Rotate Prototype\\filtered"
dir = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Rotate Prototype\\filtered")

files = 0
for files in dir:
    if files.lower().endswith('.bvh'):
        try:

            bpy.ops.object.delete() # Deletes the cube

            bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh(filepath="C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Rotate Prototype\\filtered\\pick_001_3_fil_Take_001.bvh", axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.bvh", target='ARMATURE', global_scale=1.0, frame_start=1, use_fps_scale=False, update_scene_fps=False, update_scene_duration=False, use_cyclic=False, rotate_mode='NATIVE') # We import a bvh file with the appropriate settings

            bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 72  # We configure the frame rate

            bpy.ops.export_anim.bvh(filepath="C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Rotate Prototype\\trolled\\haha.bvh", check_existing=True, filter_glob="*.bvh", global_scale=1.0, frame_start=1, frame_end=1515, rotate_mode='XYZ', root_transform_only=True) # We export the file with the appropriate settings

        except:
                print ("Couldn't open file")                
files++
```

Comment: I don't think files++ is valid python code.

Comment: What's your question? If you are having an error, show your output with the error.

Comment: What does `files++` supposes to do? If it's counting imported files it should be indented in the try clause. Anyway python doesn't allow `++` operator so use `files += 1`

Comment: As written, it doesn't look like you're actually opening/using any of the files in the `for` loop.

Comment: it is not an error...the problem is that the code reads only one file and i want every bvh file for rotation etc. About the command  files++ yes i am not sure if is correct either.

Comment: @VinayakKolagi I was wondering the same. Meanwhile my question about Qt is lost in the shuffle... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the actual file in the for loop. You're just using the same hardcoded path each time.

Maybe you want something like the below?

I renamed `files` to `file_path` to better represent what's in that variable. Then I used that value in the call to `import_anim.bvh`, and then I used it again in the call to `export_anim.bvh`. (There I tacked on `"_exported.bvh"` to the end of the file name. I wasn't really sure what you were trying to do.)

```
for file_path in dir:
    if file_path.lower().endswith('.bvh'):
        try:
            bpy.ops.object.delete() # Deletes the cube

            # We import a bvh file with the appropriate settings
            bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh(filepath=file_path,
                axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.bvh",
                target='ARMATURE', global_scale=1.0, frame_start=1,
                use_fps_scale=False, update_scene_fps=False,
                update_scene_duration=False, use_cyclic=False,
                rotate_mode='NATIVE')

            bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 72  # We configure the frame rate

            # We export the file with the appropriate settings
            bpy.ops.export_anim.bvh(
                filepath=file_path + '_exported.bvh',
                check_existing=True, filter_glob="*.bvh",
                global_scale=1.0, frame_start=1, frame_end=1515,
                rotate_mode='XYZ', root_transform_only=True)

        except:
            print ("Couldn't open file")
```

Comment: Exceptions such as FileNotFoundError should be treated as such. Avoid try catches in which you are not treating the error but just catching anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `files` for both counting and holding the current file path in each iteration.  And in the iteration you don't input the current file path to `import_anim`, you just used a hard coded file path.
Also, `++` is not a valid syntax.

```
files = 0
for file_path in dir:
    if file_path.lower().endswith('.bvh'):
        try:
            bpy.ops.object.delete() # Deletes the cube
            bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh(filepath=file_path, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.bvh", target='ARMATURE', global_scale=1.0, frame_start=1, use_fps_scale=False, update_scene_fps=False, update_scene_duration=False, use_cyclic=False, rotate_mode='NATIVE') # We import a bvh file with the appropriate settings
            bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 72  # We configure the frame rate
            bpy.ops.export_anim.bvh(filepath=file_path, check_existing=True, filter_glob="*.bvh", global_scale=1.0, frame_start=1, frame_end=1515, rotate_mode='XYZ', root_transform_only=True) # We export the file with the appropriate settings
            files += 1
        except:
            print ("Couldn't open file: {}".format(file_path))
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using bvh functions right? Debug your code, print is you friend.